Why does SVG mask become partially transparent with "use"
The two code blocks below are the same, except for the "use" tag in the second to attempt to reuse the #p1 circle.
Why does switching to "use" result in the mask becoming partially transparent? And is there a method to maintain the opacity, yet reuse the #p1 circle?


<style>
  svg { background-color:#aaa }
  #p1 { fill:blue }
  #p2 { fill:red }
  #p3 { fill:green }
</style>
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <circle r="65" cx="150" cy="100" fill="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="p1" r="65" cx="150" cy="100" />
  <circle id="p2" r="65" cx="180" cy="175" />
  <circle id="p3" r="65" cx="100" cy="175" mask="url(#m1)" />
  <circle r="45" cx="150" cy="150" fill="white" />
</svg>





<style>
  svg { background-color:#aaa }
  #p1 { fill:blue }
  #p2 { fill:red }
  #p3 { fill:green }
</style>
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <use href="#p1" fill="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="p1" r="65" cx="150" cy="100" />
  <circle id="p2" r="65" cx="180" cy="175" />
  <circle id="p3" r="65" cx="100" cy="175" mask="url(#m1)" />
  <circle r="45" cx="150" cy="150" fill="white" />
</svg>




#p1 is blue. The fill of #p1 is set in css and is overwriting the fill attribute of the use

It is intuitive to think that a fill attribute specified directly on an element would be higher priority than a CSS rule. But this is in fact false. Masks are based on luminosity, so blue produces a semi-transparent mask.

Like commented this has nothing to do with the <use> element itself.
If I take your second example, and move the <use> element from the mask to the end of the SVG, you can see the fill color -- it is blue even though you have the fill attribute value set to black. Like Michael Mullany mentions in the comment, that makes the mask semi transparent.


<style>
  svg { background-color:#aaa }
  #p1 { fill:blue }
  #p2 { fill:red }
  #p3 { fill:green }
</style>
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="p1" r="65" cx="150" cy="100" />
  <circle id="p2" r="65" cx="180" cy="175" />
  <circle id="p3" r="65" cx="100" cy="175" mask="url(#m1)" />
  <circle r="45" cx="150" cy="150" fill="white" />
  <use href="#p1" fill="black" />
</svg>



My guess  is that you would like to make the circles cover each other, so that it looks like they are intertwined. You can do that by having a mask that "reveals" the current circle, but covers the previous one.


<svg viewBox="0 0 220 200" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <use href="#p1" fill="white" />
      <use href="#p1" fill="black" transform="rotate(-120)" />
    </mask>
    <circle id="p1" r="65" cy="-40"/>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(110 110)">
    <use href="#p1" fill="blue" mask="url(#mask)" />
    <use href="#p1" fill="red" mask="url(#mask)" transform="rotate(120)" />
    <use href="#p1" fill="green" mask="url(#mask)" transform="rotate(240)" />
  </g>
</svg>



